# Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've written this script but for some reasons it's gave me some errors and I dont understand why

This is what I have :

```
   conn.Open();
    int maxRow = Int32.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

    sSql = "select * from P_MKZGood";
    if (flag == true)
    {
        sSql += "where IsCommend = 1";
    }
    cmd.CommandText = sSql;
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    ArrayList gInfos = new ArrayList();
    GoodsInfo gInfo;

    for (int i = 0; i < maxRow; i++)
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            gInfo = new GoodsInfo();
```

Error =

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '='.]

```
    int maxRow = Int32.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

What is wrong in that part? Thanks!

Fixed now , thanks guys , how stupid I feel with this error ;)

Comment: just add a space before your where clause. Something like this: `sSql += " where IsCommend = 1";`

Answer (score 6):

Your SQL string needs a space between `P_MKZGood` and `where`.

Comment: Although this probably does need to be done, it is not a proper answer to the question. Should be a comment.

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean

Comment: @CoreyOgburn this is probably exactly why the OP is receiving the error, and is an answer.

Comment: I misread the question.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, you added an image of the asp.net error, which is showing you the line number where you get a SqlException:

```
int maxRow = Int32.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

Whatever the value of cmd.CommandText is at this point (I can't tell because you haven't included the code above this line) most likely has a t-sql syntax error similar to the one further down in your code that I have called out below:

Try adding a space after your table name:

```
sSql = "select * from P_MKZGood ";
```

With the current code, if flag is set to true then you would create the following t-sql Command Text:

> select * from P_MKZGoodwhere IsCommend = 1

Notice how there is no space between **P_MKZGood** and **where**. This is a syntax violation that causes the SqlException to be thrown.

Comment: The error points to this part : int maxRow = Int32.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/65BLggv.png

Comment: @user2345156 that's because of the call to `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` being on the same line. You're receiving a SQL error because you have an invalid SQL statement.

Comment: @user2345156 `int maxRow = Int32.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());` before this line are you set `cmd.CommandText`? can you update question with that?

Answer (score 0):

@SLaks and @Phage have pointed out exactly what your problem is, but I wanted to add my own two cents. If you put a breakpoint on the line `cmd.CommandText = sSql;` you will see that `sSql`, when `flag == true`, is equal to `select * from P_MKZGoodwhere IsCommend = 1`. (That is, there is no space between `P_MKZGood` and `where`.)

What you need is `select * from P_MKZGood where IsCommend = 1`. I suggest adding a space to the beginning of

```
sSql += "where IsCommend = 1";
```

so it is, instead,

```
sSql += " where IsCommend = 1";
```

Comment: Yeah I fixed them now , thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your previous and this question I think you need method like below. There are many mistakes and places you can improve in your coding as others mentioned. check below code.

```
public List<GoodsInfo> GetGoodsList(bool flag)
{
    List<GoodsInfo> gInfos = new List<GoodsInfo>();
    using (SqlConnection sConn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Conn"].ToString()))
    {
        sConn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand sCmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            sCmd.Connection = sConn;
            sCmd.CommandText = "select * from P_MKZGood" + (flag ? " where IsCommend = 1" : string.Empty); 

            using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = sCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    GoodsInfo gInfo = new GoodsInfo();
                    gInfo.G_ID = Int32.Parse(sqlReader["G_ID"].ToString());
                    gInfo.G_Name = sqlReader["G_Name"].ToString();
                    gInfo.Type = sqlReader["Type"].ToString();
                    gInfo.GoodsType = sqlReader["GoodsType"].ToString();
                    gInfos.Add(gInfo);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return gInfos;
}
```

Few points:

- Better to user typed list like `List<GoodsInfo>` rather than using ArrayList which is not type safe.
- You don't need to get Max record to iterate all the records. you can use  `while (sqlReader.Read())`
- when you sql statement always remember to add spaces before joining.
- You can use `using` blocks with disposable objects and you don't need to close the connection etc by code.
- when you get values from reader those values can be null. add proper validations to handle null values.

Answer (score 0):

In Your statement the string on code

```
 sSql = "select * from P_MKZGood"
if (flag == true)
{
    sSql += "where IsCommend = 1";
}
```

> Final string here is : select * from P_MKZGoodwhere IsCommend = 1"

There will be error "incorrect syntax near = "

> You need to specify the space before or After "P_MKZGood" like this

```
 sSql = "select * from P_MKZGood "
```

or

```
 sSql += " where Iscommend = 1"
```

> Then final string will be : select * from P_MKZGood where IsCommend = 1"

No Error is here